# How to sed seed date for EF Core Required Properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am getting the error when doing a unit test.

`System.InvalidOperationException : The seed entity for entity type 'Country' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'SoftDeleted'.`

My Country Class is below:

```
    public class Country
    {
        public Country()
        {
            SoftDeleted = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the country.
        /// </summary>
        [Required, NotNull]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the region to which the country belongs.
        /// </summary>
        public Region? Region { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The ID used for the employee table. This will be an identity column in the database.
        /// </summary>
        [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a GUID unique ID for this entity.
        /// </summary>
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Boolean value to determine if the record has been soft deleted or not. Where 1 is softdeleted and 0 is *NOT* soft deleted.
        /// </summary>
        public bool SoftDeleted { get; set; } 
    }
```

My DBConctext has this in it for OnModelCreateing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(u =>
{
    u.Property(b => b.UniqueId).HasDefaultValueSql("newId()");
    u.Property(b => b.SoftDeleted).HasDefaultValue(false);
    u.HasQueryFilter(x => !x.SoftDeleted); //Ingore the record if it is "soft deleted".
    u.HasIndex(x => x.SoftDeleted);
});
```

So, I don't understand why I am getting this error. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Please add the code on your unit test, it is very likely there's the problem.

Comment: Most likely the problem is caused by `.HasDefaultValue(false)`